# Why is the destroyer disappearing when I summon him?

Tags: terraria-mobile

My son is playing Terraria Mobile Edition. When he summons the destroyer, it breaks and disappears. How can he fight it?

UPDATE: We can get the Destroyer to spawn (by summoning him at night using the Mechanical Worm), **BUT** then he disappears and breaks into segments, and **doesn't drop the expected items.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain your situation better? What does "but then he disappears" mean? Is it when it's killed? Randomly? When one segment breaks?

Comment: I'm passing on second hand info, here! As it's my son who's asking...! I'll get him to take a couple of screen shots when he plays later.

Comment: He says he hasn't killed it, because the Destroyer splits after just a few seconds.

Comment: To quote the wiki, "The Destroyer, unlike the Eater of Worlds, does not break apart when individual pieces lose all of their HP.". While I doubt that helps, it further supports my theory that you have hit a weird bug. There is even a listed bug for console, where the destroyer acts like the eater of worlds.

Answer (score 2):

The Destroyer is summonable from 7:30 p.m to 4:30 a.m. You can check the hour on a Grandfather Clock.

Be sure to use the Mechanical Worm at night.

[Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Destroyer)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from summoning him at night, there is a bug in which when the player summons the boss at too much of a height, the boss will fly off screen just disappear. I would suggest summoning him with the mechanical worm at a lower area and, if the attack pattern makes the boss go towards the sky, not to follow him with wings. Again, if the boss goes too high into the air, the entity simply disappears. (I believe this is a mobile only bug, as well.) If this is not the case, it could be a bug that the Terraria Devs would like to see. You may want to submit a bug report to them.

EDIT: I did do a little research on this, and besides the glitch above, where the boss despawns when too close to the border, I found this on the wikia:

> On mobile version, if you fight The Destroyer near the edge of the world and his head goes out of the world, the head will be replaced with the nearest mob. The Destroyer's body will follow the "head" and after a little while, the Destroyer will die with no death message or drops.
>   ([Source](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/The_Destroyer))

There are a couple other bugs which cause the Destroyer to act oddly, you may want to check the behaviors of the bug.